# How to take a photo from the webcam using the built-in button?

Tags: delphi, webcam

I have a USB-Based Camera with a Capture Button that takes a picture. However, this feature only works in a dedicated application. I think the button sends a signal that triggers an image capture function.
Do you have any idea how to capture this signal so that I can use this button in my application?

I checked in IrfanView and after selecting a TWAIN driver I can see the image from the webcam. I can press the acquire button and the picture saves on the disk.
But pressing a button on the camera does nothing.
It probably triggers some other event.

P.S. I Use Delphi

Comment: If you can setup the Cam so it saves the picture in a certain folder, then your Delphi app could monitor that folder.

Comment: But I need to take a picture with built-in button

Comment: Dig thru the manuals. Use your google-fu. This has nothing to do with programming ,its specific for your camera. If you cant find it, ask the manufacturer about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TWAIN scanning components for Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059343/twain-scanning-components-for-delphi)

Comment: I think it _is_ a programming issue, especially how to make a Delphi application respond to commands from a [TWAIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TWAIN) enabled device, like a flatbed scanner or this camera. There is another question about TWAIN and Delphi, so I suggest you start digging in those answers (which mostly point to open sourced libraries, including [this one](http://www.kluug.net/delphitwain.php) by @oxo). If you bump into specific problems using those, you can ask a more specific question about that, with which we are hopefully able to help out.

Comment: Okay, I think I misinterpreted the question there. The button on the camera seems to  behave in a non-standard way, so I'm not sure if those libraries would help.